# "missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed" error in GA package

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization, genetic-algorithm

When running a genetic algorithm using the GA package, I am receiving a "missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed" error. In my code below, `like` is a function for fitness and `X` is a numeric vector of length 6.

```
library(GA)
y<-c(46,38,49,55)
W<-matrix(c(0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0),ncol=4)
ei<-eigen(W)$values
data<- matrix(c(14691,14150,14607,15140,5337,5386,5207,5178),ncol=2)
         like=function(x)
            {
              co<-c(x[2],x[3])  
              e<-x[4]*W%*%y-data%*%co-x[1]
              L<-30*log(2)-15*log(2*pi)+log(prod(1-x[4]*Re(ei)))-15*log(x[5])+sum(log(pnorm(-x[6]*e/sqrt(x[5]))))
              -0.5/x[5]*t(e)%*%e
              return(L)
            }
    GA <- ga(type = "real-valued", 
             fitness =  like,
             min=c(-100,0,-50,-10,0.001,0),
             max=c(100,100,0,10,100,10),
             popSize = 100, maxiter = 200,
             optim = TRUE)
```

The result and error are as below:

```
GA | iter = 1 
Mean =      -Inf | Best = -2.870387 
Error in if (fmin > (sfactor * fave - fmax)/(sfactor - 1)) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a cryptic error, but a good hint of the problem is in the iteration 1 summary information:

> Mean =      -Inf | Best = -2.870387

The average objective value from your function is negative infinity, meaning some iterate is returning objective value negative infinity. A bit of debugging code identifies sample data that gives this issue:

```
x <- c(-3.2, 5.7, -26.9, -6.1, 37, 9)
like(x)
# [1] -Inf
```

Since you are maximizing, you could just cap the returned function value at a sensible lower bound, for instance by replacing `return(L)` with `return(pmax(L, -1e6))`. Then you get sensible results:

> GA | iter = 200
>
> Mean = 102.2197 | Best = 106.0328  | Final local search = 106.0328

Comment: I change sqrt(x[5]) with a new x[5] in the definition of function like and it works.I think  negative infinity is caused by log (0).Thanks for your help.